# dynamically set WCF baseAddressPrefixFilters

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service that I am deploying in a shared hosting environment.  Because of this I have to specify [baseAddressPrefixFilters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924481.aspx) (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506634/wcf-config-element-baseaddressprefixfilters) for why this is necessary). Setting the base address prefix filters happens in the web.config like so...

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://example.com"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

The problem is that I have multiple environments that are configured this way with their own urls (i.e. dev, test, prod)

I tried the following with no luck...

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://dev.example.com"/>
    <add prefix="http://test.example.com"/>
    <add prefix="http://example.com"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

So the question is how do I set the baseAddressPrefixFilter dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running under IIS7, this is a good walk through of the problem and solution.  If not, the information for the WCF side is still what you need to know to resolve your issues.

http://keithelder.net/2008/04/28/configuring-wcf-and-iis-7-with-http-bindings-and-multiple/

Have you looked at the ServiceHostFactory?  We used this in our 3.0 services to work with the different host headers.

http://blogs.msdn.com/rampo/archive/2007/06/15/supporting-multiple-iis-bindings-per-site.aspx

Comment: thanks for the reply.  unfortunately the environment is IIS6 and I'm looking for a runtime solution rather than a server config solution since it is a shared hosting environment.

Comment: this seems to be the best approach right now.  going to mark this as the answer.